# City dropdown values on checkout page changes to other store cities on browser autocomplete

Tags: checkout, multistore, magento2.3.1, dropdown-options, city

*I am facing a very strange issue where the city dropdown shows the cities of KSA and when the user selects his dubai address from browser's autocomplete option in street address field*

*the city dropdown values also changes to show all UAE cities while the user is still in KSA store.*

*This is a 2 store website and I am using EAdesign ROMcity extension for city dropdown feature. Any help would mean a lot.*